# How To List All Dates Between Two Dates In Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, epplus

I have tried the formula to generate dates between start date and end date and it is not working properly.. I would need help here

[Image from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9dFZ.png)

formula = `=IF($D$5+ROW(D5)>=$D$6-1,"",F5+1)`

The above formula is only giving value upto 9 Nov and after that its is not working. Please help me to generate dates between start date and end date

Comment: If you version of Excel has SEQUENCE() then use that.

Answer (score 4):

*If you have an up-to-date version of Excel*, you will have the very useful `SEQUENCE()` function. It generates a dynamic array of numbers.

For an inclusive range (including Start and End dates), use the formula:

```
=B2+SEQUENCE(1+B3-B2,,0)
```

For an exclusive range (excluding Start and End dates), use the formula:

```
=B2+SEQUENCE(B3-B2-1)
```

The result is a dynamic array of dates, which will grow or contract as the Start and End dates are changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the formulas like this

```
=IF($D$5+ROW(D5)-5>=$D$6-1,"",F5+1)
```

Comment: this is not working. Only until the 14th

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to lock the Row(D5)

```
=IF($D$5+ROW($D$5)>=$D$6-1,"",F5+1)
```

[image]