# List of dates between a list of start and end dates EXCEL Formulas only

Tags: excel-formula

I want to list all the dates between a list of start and end dates. I am looking for one single formula to work irrespective of any number of rows I have. Any help is highly appreciated. I have copied the image below from [Google sheets - List of dates between a list of start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391994/google-sheets-list-of-dates-between-a-list-of-start-and-end-dates) because this is exactly what I need except for Excel Formula. This is for an environment that does not allow me to install any thing apart from Excel

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To List All Dates Between Two Dates In Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724274/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-excel)

Comment: @A.Steer that only takes one row, the question contains multiple date ranges.

Comment: That is correct How To List All Dates Between Two Dates In Excel does not cover multiple ranges.