How to determine if a certain weekday is within a date/time range in Excel
I have an Excel spreadsheet (v 2019/2021, not 365) that has [DateTimeIn] and [DateTimeOut] columns.  I need a formula that checks how many weekdays have elapsed between the two dates, filtering out any dates that fall on a Holidays table, and note if any weekday of the included results range is a Wednesday.
The purpose of this is to calculate swap fees for a Trading Journal, where swap fees (I'll calculated this separately) are a regular amount (1x) at the close of the trading day (1700 ET) unless the ending trading day is Wednesday, wherein the swap fee will be (3x).
So the question is, ignoring the unasked questions, how do I take a date/time range (two columns added/subtracted from each other - this already works) and determine if the resulting date/time value is:

A weekday.
If a weekday, the if a Wednesday.
If the trade close date/time is after the close of the market (1700 ET).

For same-day trades, I only need to check if the close time is after the market close.  For overnight trades, I need to check to see how many trading day have elapsed, and whether or not that trading days range contains a Wednesday.
Any ideas?  I'm not an Excel expert, otherwise I would have posted some attempts.  Thanks in advance.

You can check answers in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724274/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-excel. that is, list all dates between start date and end date, and then which of those dates are Wednesdays, and which are holidays...

On second thought, if you just need to count number of weekdays, and number of Wednesday, you can use NETWORKDAYS.INTL function.

You can use below formula to calculate number of working days, and number of working Wednesdays between two dates:
I put a list of holidays in a range called "holidays".

=LET(
    dates, SEQUENCE(INT(B2) - INT(A2), 1, INT(A2), 1),
    isHoliday, MMULT(--(dates = TRANSPOSE(holidays)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(holidays), 1, 1, 0)),
    dayOfWeeks, WEEKDAY(dates, 1),
    isSaturday, dayOfWeeks = 7,
    isSunday, dayOfWeeks = 1,
    isWednesday, dayOfWeeks = 4,
    isWorkingDay, (--NOT(isHoliday)) * (--NOT(isSaturday)) * (--NOT(isSunday)),
    isWorkingWednesday, isWorkingDay * isWednesday,
    numWorkingDays, SUM(isWorkingDay),
    numWorkingWednesday, SUM(isWorkingWednesday),
    HSTACK(numWorkingWednesday, numWorkingDays - numWorkingWednesday)
)

It mainly uses SEQUENCE(INT(B2) - INT(A2), 1, INT(A2), 1) to list all dates between start date (in A2) and end date (in B2).
Then uses MMULT(--(dates = TRANSPOSE(holidays)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(holidays), 1, 1, 0)) to check whether those dates are holidays.
It also uses WEEKDAY to check whether a date is Saturday, Sunday, or Wednesday.
